# Validating an app's feature

Tags: requirements, validation

I am currently coding a productive study app. In my app, the user can input a list of productive, non-productive and necessary tasks which he will be doing throughout a period of time. The user is able to click which task he is going to work on and the app will track the time he has spent on that specific task. At the end, the app will display different pie charts showing the time he spent on each task. One of the features that my app will have is that it will track the rate at which the user changes his task from the productive to non-productive tag in one hour and it would take the average among different hours. The idea is that if his switch rate is too high then it means that he is not being productive. How can I support the validity of the feature? like how do I show that the switch rate would show whether the user is being productive or not?. Do I have to support it with some research?

I am currently taking a software engineering course and I have to present the app to the whole class. The thing is that if I claim to have added that specific feature on the app, someone may ask "where is the research that supports that this feature would indeed show wheter I am being productive or not?"

Comment: Ask your teacher these questions.  He's in the best position to answer them.

Comment: This isn't a question about software engineering, but about cognitive differences between workflow styles. it should probably be on ux.stackexchange,com.

Answer (score 1):

Answer with "The market will decide"

If you were trying to get funding to produce the app, then yes you would have to convince people that its a good feature. Maybe with research and user studies.

But you have already completed the software, you only have to convince your customers to buy it. Which is best done with yellow and red stickers, pictures of women smiling at the camera and giving free versions to reporters to write about. Not academic articles